# On-screen keyboard not appearing when editing text fields in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, text, keyboard, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard not Appearing when Tapping Text Box in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312680/keyboard-not-appearing-when-tapping-text-box-in-uiwebview)

I have a web view which displays a simple login form, containing username and password fields.

However when the user clicks in one of the text fields, although the cursor appears in the text field, the on-screen keyboard does not appear.

I've tried registering for UIKeyboardWillShowNotifications notifications and I see this notification arrive, however the keyboard doesn't actually appear on the screen.  I've also tried sending the web view to the back of the view hierarchy and changing it's frame so it doesn't occupy the whole screen.  However neither of these measures have solved the problem.

What would people recommend trying next?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved this problem by creating a new Xcode project and transferring all the source files across - so it looks like it was some kind of build or project configuration problem.