# UIWebView not Displaying Keypad

Tags: ios5, uiwebview

I been trying to debug a problem with some odd behaviour inside a UIWebView.  My app uses a UIWebView to display a custom form to collect certain information.  When the form is first loaded, filled and submitted, everything behaves as it should.  After the first submit, when the form is reloaded, the keypad will not display (but the content scrolls as though it is).

The only solution I have come across is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337936/620197), but this does not seem like the solution to my problem since that line is already in my app delegate.

Is this a known issue?  I don't even know where to start looking to debug this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching SO and Apple forums, it was the view hierarchy that was getting rearranged.  In my particular case, a progress indicator was being added as new window (by a coworker, so I can blame someone else for this).  The trick was not set this new as the key window and only manipulate the the hidden properties

This is just a quick fix because it was only one line of code that was causing this major problem.