# Equivalent of textFieldShouldBeginEditing for UIWebView

Tags: ios

In an UITextField, I can capture the event of keyboard showing up by using `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //handle things here
}
```

However this is not possible for UIWebView, is there any thing equivalent to solve the problem?

Edit:
I want to know about the text field as well, let say whether it is an password field. UIKeyboardDidShowNotification won't help. And I also want to tamper the keyboard if the text is an password field, so javascript won't help either.

Comment: keyboard notifications?

Comment: I want to know about the text filed as well, let say whether it is an password field. UIKeyboardDidShowNotification won't help.

Comment: Is it your html source or any page that user can navigate to?

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShowWithNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHideWithNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: I want to know about the text filed as well, let say whether it is an password field. UIKeyboardDidShowNotification won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webview to display your data, then you can handle events using javascrips & jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[Keyboard not Appearing when Tapping Text Box in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312680/keyboard-not-appearing-when-tapping-text-box-in-uiwebview)